# Inicio de sesion no esta funcionando php oracle

Tags: php, oracle

Hola cuando trato de iniciar sesión simplemente no funciona, deberia entrar al if y escribir un mensaje "ADELANTE" pero no funciona (entra al else) he buscado mucho tiempo el error pero no lo encuentro.
Me cercioré de que los datos esten bien, y probe con mas tablas de la BD de Schema pero tampoco con nada funciona... No me indica ningun error ni nada la consola tampoco

Aqui está el codigo

**Pagina 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sistema de login</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }

        table{
            width: 25%;
            background-color: #FFC;
            border: 2px dotted #F00;
            margin: auto; 
        }

        .izq{
            text-align: right;
        }
        .der{
            text-align: left;
        }
        td{
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!--SE REALIZARÁ ESTE SISTEMA DE LOGIN DE DOS FORMAS, PRIMERO USANDO LA LIBRERIA PDO Y LUEGO USANDO POO+PDO-->

<h1> INRODUCE TUS DATOS</h1>

<form action = "59sistema_login2.php" method="post"> <!-- con el form action indico a que pagina quiero que rediriga este formulario cuando la persona pulse un boton de enviar y para pasar la info desde esta pagina a 59sistema_login2.php utilizo el metodo post.-->

<table>
    <tr><td class="izq">Login:</td><td class="der"><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr><tr><td class="izq">Password:</td><td class ="der"><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="LOGIN"></td></tr> 
<table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Pagina 2:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    try
    {
        $base = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost', 'hr','hr');
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=:login AND MANAGER_ID=:password";
        $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
        $login = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"])); //htmlentities convierte cualquier simbolo (una comilla, un guion bajo por ejemplo) al html. addslashes escapa cualquier caracter de este tipo (comilla, etc) con el objetivo de evitar la inyeccion sql
        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login); //como ahora no uso parametros, ya no necesito bindParam, ahora uso parametros como :lohin y :password por eso es BindValue
        $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

        $resultado->execute();

        $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount(); //rowcount devuelve el numero de registros que se obtuvo en una consulta, si no existe el usuario entonces devolverá un 0.

        echo "valor: $numero_registro<br><br>";
        echo "$login con $password";

        if($numero_registro!=0) //el usuario existe
        {
            echo "<h2>Adelante!!</h2>";

        }
        else //dentro del else redirigiré a la propia pagina del login
        {
            header("location:59sistema_login.php"); //redirigo a la pag login
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die("Error: " .$e->getMessage());
    }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**

cree un nuevo archivo y probe poniendo esto y me imprime el CONEXION OK, o sea la conexion estaria bien (?)

```
<?php
    try
    { 
         $base = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost', 'hr','hr'); 
        echo "Conexión OK!";
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        die('Error: ' .$e->GetMessage()); //getmessage es una funcion o metodo del objeto e
    }

    finally
    {
        $base = null; //vacio la memoria
    }
?>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Ejecuté esta linea de codigo para ver si estan bien instalados los drivers.

```
<?php foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    echo $driver, '\n';
?>
```

El codigo muestra: mysql\noci\nsqlite\n

Comment: El código esta bien.. pero me temo que el problema está en la conexión a Oracle `oci`... [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712045/connect-pdo-with-oracle-database) puedes leer sobre la conexión hacia Oracle.. comprueba que tengas todas las configuraciones necesarias... ¿Que te imprime si haces un: `var_dump($base);`?

Comment: lo raro es que cuando me conecto con otro archivo que tengo funciona bien :S usando el pdo(...) de l misma forma que aquí (el codigo lo puse arriba debjado de "UPDATE". Probe poniendo var_dump y me imprime esto object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: @aldanux asumo que eso al codigo que me refiero que funciona bien es por el hecho de que me imprime CONEXION OK, está en el primer UPDATE del codigo editado

Comment: @aldanux Cambié el select por un insert y ahi si aparece el mensaje "Adelante" y los echo muestra son los siguientes
el 1,7777 con 200,object(PDO)#1 (0) { },Adelante!!
pero cuando hago un select muestra 0 en el numero de filas afectadas, parece que el problema es rowCount :S no sé porque no funciona.